# Creating mock object in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock a class which is actually not part of test program. i.e. 
My test program TestA.helloTest() calls class A's method hello() and A.hello() calls class B's greetings().

TestA.helloTest() -> A.hello() -> B.greetings()

I'd like my class A to use a mock object for B instead of actual implementation as it some security stuff which is not relevant to test programs objective.

There are several classes like B exists in code and probably we cannot get to modify them due to its sensitive nature. The problem is, class B is neither part of dependency injection nor implements any interface. I know its a bad practice, this code was written almost when I was kindergarden. :)

I think we can inject mock only within the context of test program. Is there a way to make class A uses a mock object for class B (or C, D, E) instead of its actual implementation by negotiating with JVM or Mockito ?

I'd appreciate any thoughts/inputs.

Comment: Why cant you just use Mockito

Comment: As @cowls says, a mocking library such as Mockito can do that for you; if your class is final however you'll have to use PowerMockito.

Comment: Guys, he knows that he may use Mockito! What he asks is if Mockito can mock a class which does not implement an interface.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts of your question.

1. "Class B is not a part of dependency injection": well, it must be possible to use dependency injection to mock it, but it's enough if you may inject class B into **your** class A - but class A is **your** class so you may easily implement it in any way you need!
2. "Class B does not implement any interface": Mockito can mock also a (non-final) class. As *fge* wrote in the comment, if B is final, you use PowerMockito instead.

ADDED: There is one possible hack in case you cannot edit the class A. In your test project, create the same class B with your mock functionality in the same package and put the jar (or class folder) to your classpath BEFORE the original package with the class B. JVM will use your class instead of the original one :D

Comment: Thank you @Honza. I thought about option #1 from your suggestion. But I will not be able to modify class A, as my scope is limited to test programs. It seems I dont have lot of options anyway!

Comment: @bkrish, these too points are not options :) They were part of your sentence and I just split them to answer both of them :) But there is one more option, kind of a hack, see my edit of the answer.

Comment: Now I am able to mock the class "B" using JMockit without changing of legacy code and trying to do the same with Mockito. If it doesnot work for any reason, I would prefer having a mock class in jar file with same package as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to introduce `BDelegate` which calls `B's` methods (i.e. it delegates everything to `B`) but it has a nice unit-test friendly API. Then you can replace all direct usages of `B` in the code with `BDelegate` and clean your tests.

Since the code in `BDelegate` is so simple, you don't need unit tests for most methods.

Another solution is to change `B`. Yes, I know "it's not possible etc." :-) Actually, it is *possible* but not *cheap*. My solution here is to create a new project, put the JAR into it which contains the class file for `B`. Then write a new, better class `B` in that project and use the JAR to compile it.

This will work because for the compile, source code always comes first. So `B` will be taken from the sources while everything else will come from the JAR (so your new copy of `B` will compile).

Now you can change `B` in some ways (not in all ways but it gives you some leeway). When the new `B` compiles, you just replace the old class files in the old JAR with the new ones to get a better `B`.

That gives your a patched JAR file which you can then use in your projects. I use this approach to fix bugs in the Java Runtime, OSS projects that reject my patches or the Oracle JDBC drivers, to name a few.